# Data conversion using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression, etl

I have the following expression that works perfectly,

```
ISNULL(LateDays < 0 ? (DT_WSTR,30)OriginalTransactionAmount : "") ? "0"
: (LateDays < 0 ? (DT_WSTR,30)OriginalTransactionAmount : "")
```

The issue is that OriginalTransactionAmount is decimal, and I want the whole expression to be decimal. LateDats is (DT_14) integer. When I try to replace the DT_WSTR it gives me an error. Any clue on how I can make it decimal?

I am using this data in a report, and it's giving me a hard time, because the reporting tool is reading it as a text.

Comment: What happens when you put (DT_DECIMAL, 2) in front of each LateDays instance?

Comment: If I put decimal without changing the " " to a simple 0 it gives an error, because having the "" male the wole thing a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced the `" "` with `"0"`. Then after that added a data conversion task and changed it to decimal and it works.

```
ISNULL(LateDays < 0 ? (DT_WSTR,30)OriginalTransactionAmount : "0") ? "0" 
: (LateDays < 0 ? (DT_WSTR,30)OriginalTransactionAmount : "0")
```

Comment: You have to accept this answer, even if it is yours. Also if other answer was helpful, it is good to up vote them.

Answer (score 1):

Break it into pieces:

```
isnull(LateDays) ? (DT_NUMERIC,18,2) 0 :

LateDays < 0 ? (DT_NUMERIC,18,2) OriginalTransactionAmount : (DT_NUMERIC,18,2) 0
```

LateDays is in the Boolean portion and is not a result. All results have to be the same data type.

Answer (score 1):

## The Issue

The issue cause is that when using `? :` conditional operators, both false and true result must have the same data type. So when using `LateDays < 0 ? (DT_NUMERIC,18,2)OriginalTransactionAmount : ""` there are one Decimal result and one String result, you can use the following expression instead of this *(replace `""` with `NULL(DT_NUMERIC)`:

```
ISNULL(LateDays < 0 ? (DT_NUMERIC,18,2)OriginalTransactionAmount : NULL(DT_NUMERIC,18,2)) ? (DT_NUMERIC,18,2)0 
: (LateDays < 0 ? (DT_NUMERIC,18,2)OriginalTransactionAmount : NULL(DT_NUMERIC,18,2))
```

## Other Suggestion

Try using `REPLACENULL()` function

```
(REPLACENULL(LateDays,0) < 0) ? (DT_NUMERIC,18,2)OriginalTransactionAmount : (DT_NUMERIC,18,2) 0
```